# Handle a click event in django-tables2

Tags: django, django-tables2

I am starting to use `django-tables2` and I have added a column which should allow user to delete a record when the user clicks on the button. The code looks as follows:

```
class ReviewTable(tables.Table):

    delete = tables.LinkColumn('review_delete', args=[tables.A('pk')], orderable=False,
                               empty_values=(), verbose_name='')

    def render_delete(self, record):
        url = static('remove.png')
        href = '#'
        return mark_safe('<a href="' + href + '" Delete><img src="' + url + '"></a>')
```

This basically enders the image fine in a column but all I can do is set the link to it. How can I get it to call some method where I can then filter by the record ID and delete the relevant record? Is this the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you generate HTML from code, you still have access to onclick events.

```
return mark_safe('<a href="{0}" Delete class="delete" onclick='delete_action()'><img src="{1}"></a>'.format(href, url)
```

Now your `delete_action` can be a javascript function that gives you more control. Generated HTML is basically just any old type of HTML, so you can still use [jquery event handlers](http://api.jquery.com/on/) with it

BTW, please note how string formatting has been used in stead of concatenation. This is more pythonic